# Simple code doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to move my character but he moves through the border of the scene. 
When I debug it says`charTransform has 0 0 0 coords in Vector3`.

```
Transform charTransform;
float leftHorizontalBound;
float rightHorizontalBound;

void Start()
{
   charTransform = this.transform;
   leftHorizontalBound = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0,0, camera.nearClipPlane)).x;
   rightHorizontalBound= camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (1,0, camera.nearClipPlane)).x;
}

void Update()
{
   if(charTransform.position.x <= leftHorizontalBound)
   {
      charTransform.position = new vector2(leftHorizontalBound + 0.1f);
      return;
   }
   if(charTransform.position.x >= rightHorizontalBound)
   {
      charTransform.position = new vector2(rightHorizontalBound - 0.1f);
      return;
   }

   //MAKE HERE YOUR MOVEMENT BASED ON INPUT.
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @aliboy38 why code doesn't prevent my charecter crossing the border of the screen, and why charecter always have coords x,y,z 0 0 0?

Comment: Are you setting leftHorizontalBound and rightHorizontalBound values in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

i cant exactly say what is your problem and wish you assume your problem more accurate but i think you are working something like a boad game with a fixed camera and something like a ball always moves and you just want to keep that object in the scene.

in your code you defined a position by variables and made a position check for every frame. thats not what basically is done in unity and there will be problems. you can make an empty object and put in on the borders you want and check the position of that object with your moving object.

your next way is make an object and add a collider component to it. if your game is 3d add a collider and if its 2d game add a 2d collider and a collider to moving object and after that it never moves toward the borders but still there will be some limits so if it didnt work i think you should add a rigidBody to both of them.